# Capybara and Rails, why using should have_content in spec gives me "You are being redirected."?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, capybara

I'm writing an integration test for a rails application using Capybara within Rspec. After filling out a form, the user presses submit.

If I run the test I get:

> expected there to be content "Welcome to course builder" in "You are
>   being redirected."

I am trying to test the resulted page content, here is the test:

```
describe PagesController do

  describe "Quiz testing in chapter" do

    def page_view
       Capybara::Node::Simple.new(@response.body)
    end

    render_views
    login_student

    it "should fail if user chosen wrong answer" do
      page= create_quiz_page_with_two_choices_first_correct
      post :answer_quiz, :page_id=>page.id, :submitted_single_answer=>'2'
      page_view.should have_content("Welcome to course builder")

    end
  end
end
```

in the `PagesController`

```
def answer_quiz
 ...
 respond_to do |format|
   format.html { redirect_to page }
   format.json { head :ok }
 end
end
```

I just started using Capybara, so am I missing something obvious here? Why am I stuck with the redirect response?

Thanks!

hopewise

Comment: I think you should read a simple tutorial like this: http://codingfrontier.com/integration-testing-setup-with-rspec-and-capy first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`login_student` needs to go in a `before` block:

```
before(:each) do
  login_student
end
```

However even that probably won't fix the problem. When using Capybara it is recommended to actually login by visiting the login page for each example, so:

```
before(:each) do
  visit login_path # log in test user
end

it "should do something awesome" do
  visit "/awesome"
  page.should have_content("You rock!")
end
```

It's also helpful to write a special case to handle logins in the test environment, so you can avoid having to create a user for test logins.

Comment: thanks, I tried to apply your advice, but, it seems that Capybara visits the login_path and stuck there, it will not for example hit signin key and enters, then visit the "/awesome" like in your example above, how can I make it actually login ?

Comment: Capybara requires that you tell it what steps to take. For example, `visit login_path`, `fill_in :password, :with => "value"`, `click_button "Login"`. The details would depend on the specific page. I'd suggest reading the Capybara docs for more info: http://github.com/jnicklas/capybara